# Maximo login - REST command

Tags: authentication, maximo

I am trying to login to Maximo using the REST API; however, it just displays the login html content.

As per the IBM documentation:

```
POST /oslc/login
Authorization: BASIC <base64 encoded user:pass>

<no body required>
```

I tried this both on curl and via Postman. The results on both just display the Maximo login html content and does not login.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://domain/maximo/oslc/login' --header 'Authorization: Basic c5hhcmKJMTJ6aW4uaPJtLm89uEp91p13aXK900UgHjE8ODQ='
```

The username and password I encoded are valid.

I’m not sure why this fails to login: Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The quoted documentation has BASIC but your curl command has Basic. Try using the same case.

Comment: Still no luck, tried with upper case as shown in the doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Base64 string you are using for authentication doesn't decode correctly. If that wasn't on purpose (say as an example for this question), then that would be a source of trouble. Remember to take the username, append a colon, then append the password to get your source string, then base64 encode all of that.

For example, if your username is "`maxuser`" and that user's password is "`maxpass`", your source string would be "`maxuser:maxpass`", which then base64 encodes to "`bWF4dXNlcjptYXhwYXNz`"

There is also the consideration of if you are using LDAP or not. The header you have provided here is for LDAP. If you are having Maximo itself authenticate the users, then you should be using the "`maxauth`" header instead (and don't prepend the "`Basic` " text). I.e. `--header 'maxauth: bWF4dXNlcjptYXhwYXNz'`

Comment: curl --head --request POST 'https://esls1.eu.smi.ibm.com/maximo/oslc/login' --header 'maxauth:c5hhcmKJMTJ6aW4uaPJtLm89uEp91p13aXK900UgHjE8ODQ='

I got this response:

Comment: It seems your response got cut off. What happened? (Also, your base64 string doesn't seem to decode correctly again.)

Comment: According to your other question, switching to the maxauth header did not solve your problem. Your redirect (in the other question) has the "appserverauth=true" appended to it. That usually means LDAP is being used for authentication instead of local Maximo. That in turn means you need to go back to use the "Authorization" header you were initially using. Make sure your base64 encoding is correct though. So far in these posts, it hasn't been.